# inner join me duplica los datos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos tablas Tabla1 y Tablas2 ambas con un campo de Folio en comun y otras columnas que no tienen en comun.

Realizo un registro con cuatro filas en la tabla1 con el mismo folio por ejemplo el folio 10.

En la tabla2 tengo un campo donde tengo el mismo folio en comun y con otras columnas diferentes.

Quiero juntar los folio iguales y obtener las columnas entre ambas tablas y obtener el resultado en un solo query.
No todas las columnas son iguales en ambas tablas, solo el Folio.

Pero a la hora querer obtener con un `inner join` mi rsultado se duplica.

por ejemplo si tengo 4 Folios iguales en  ambas tablas, solo quiero obtener como resultado de ambas tablas 4 filas con los columnas de ambas tablas, pero lo que me esta haciendo es sacar 4 filas de cada folio, es decir 16 filas.

Si alguien pudiera orientarme, se los agradeceria.

**EDIT**

Este es el query que tengo:

```
SELECT R.FOLIO,C.CUENTA as Cuenta,R.DEPARTAMENTO as Dpto,R.CANTIDAD as Qty, 
str((C.COSTO/R.CANTIDAD),12,2) AS [Unit Price],C.COSTO as Total,R.ITEM as 
Item,R.DESCRIPCION as Description,R.UNIMEDIDA as UoM,R.NOMBRE 
FROM TABLA1 as R 
INNER Join TABLA2 as C ON C.Folio = R.FOLIO AND C.GERENTEDPTO=6650 and 
C.ESTATUS = 0 and C.RECHAZADO <> 1 and APROBACIONESOK < 4
```

**si tengo 4 Folios iguales en ambas tablas, solo quiero obtener como resultado del query de ambas tablas, 4 filas con los columnas de ambas tablas, pero lo que me esta haciendo es sacar 4 filas de cada folio, es decir 16 filas.**

**TABLAS**

Tabla1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado que espero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que hace mi query es sacarme 4 filas de cada folio y no es lo que espero.

Comment: Agregar algo de código de lo que has intentado

Comment: Puede ser por que falte alguna restricción o tu tabla no esta bien formada, podrias poner tus dos tablas y la consulta que haz intentado

Comment: Para poder orientarte tenes que mostrarnoss lo que hiciste, los datos de entrada y que salida te dio. Asi como esta, teoricamente, puede ser cualquier cosa (desde que escribiste mal la query hasta que los datos no son coo pensas)

Comment: Agregue el query que estoy haciendo, gracias por su interes.

Comment: Puedes poner los campos que conforman a ambas tablas si no es mucho

Comment: Listo, agregue la informacion solicitada.

Comment: @gbianchi puse el query que estoy utilizando y las tablas junto con el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 1):

Tu query esta bien, y la respuesta es mas que correcta.

Esa query va a hacer un producto cartesiano de todos los registros de C con R, porque la condicion de join `c.folio = r.folio` se cumple para todos los campos de las dos tablas.

Tu problema esta en que la condición de join no es solamente ese campo, son mas campos, pero nosotros no los conocemos.

Las condiciones extras que pusiste, que deberian ir en el where, se cumplen para todos los registros de tabla2, con lo cual no tienen mucho sentido.

La tabla de salida que mostras, tampoco tienen ningun sentido. Si todos son folio 18, que esperas unir y como?

Cuando le decimos en un query que queremos hacer join por un campo, no une un registro con un registro de la otra tabla. Agarra el valor de tabla1, y trae todos los registros que cumplen la condicion para tabla2, no solamente el primero (que creo que lo que genera tu confusion).

Desgraciadamente, la respuesta a esto es que esta mal la logica de la tabla que queres sacar.

Comment: Tengo un ID(identity) que identifica los folios, podria entonces cambiar la logica del query y tomar como referencia el ID y el folio.

Comment: Desconozco, vos conoces tu modelo, nosotros no. Tal vez este mal armado el modelo de las tablas. Yo por lo que mostras hasta ahora no veo forma de entender que registro se relaciona con cual. A simple vista es todos con todos.

Comment: quizas, un poco de contexto...segun la logica del sistema, primero registro en la tabla1 ID y Folio, actualmente ese folio lo utilizo en la tabla2 y segun tu respuesta mi query hace un producto cartesiano porque el folio cumple para todos, entonces tengo que registrar en tabla 2 el ID del folio registrado en tabla1 y entonces el query tendria que traer los folio con el mismo ID entre ambas tablas y ahi solo me obtendria los registros como tales, ya que los ID son unicos. Segun entiendo de tu respuesta o mas bien en teoria creo tiene logica o no?

Comment: Pareceria ser que tus tablas estan mal armadas. Si folio puede repetirse, entonces deberias tener una tabla de folios. Si a cada folio le das un Id, entonces deberias guardar en la otra tabla el Id del folio. Tu modelo no parece correcto. Tal vez es eso lo que deberiamos validar, en otra pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios, lo arregle agregando un campo mas a la tabla2 donde registro el ID del Folio de la tabla 1 y ahora ya obtengo el resultado es perado.

Comment: Y sacaste el campo folio, que no tiene sentido, no?

Answer (score 0):

has intentado realizar tu misma consulta con un WHERE para no anidar toda la consulta en el INNER. Ejemplo:

```
SELECT R.FOLIO,C.CUENTA as Cuenta,R.DEPARTAMENTO as Dpto,R.CANTIDAD as Qty, 
 str((C.COSTO/R.CANTIDAD),12,2) AS [Unit Price],C.COSTO as Total,R.ITEM as 
 Item,R.DESCRIPCION as Description,R.UNIMEDIDA as UoM,R.NOMBRE 
FROM TABLA1 as R 
INNER Join TABLA2 as C ON (C.Folio = R.FOLIO)  
WHERE C.GERENTEDPTO=6650 AND C.ESTATUS = 0 AND C.RECHAZADO <> 1 AND APROBACIONESOK < 4
```

Asi me sirvio a mi.

Comment: igual le va a devolver 16 registros. El problema es la logica, todos los campos de la tabla 2 cumplen con esas condiciones y la condicion de join une todos los registros de tabla1 con todos los de tabla2